# Can't Access my Object's Members

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, object

> Error : 'object' does not contain a definition for 'lp' and no extension method >'lp' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing >a using directive or an assembly reference?

If I try and get a value form my object I get this...

[image]

But When I run without trying to get the value, I can clearly see my object does contain lp...

[image]

Full code for Deserialize...

```
public object Deserialize(Object obj, string path)

        {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return obj;

        }
```

Person class...

```
public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }

    }
```

PersonList class...

```
public class PersonList

    {
        public List<Person> lp = new List<Person>();


        public void AddPerson(Person p)
        {
            lp.Add(p);
        }
    }
```

It's an instance of the Person List I am sending in to  public class PersonList

```
{
    public List<Person> lp = new List<Person>();


    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        lp.Add(p);
    }
}.
```

> UPDATE: I was doing casting before but I will be passing in loads of different types of objects so wanted a generic Deserialize function. is there a way to do this? –

Comment: `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` returns `object` (it has been introduced when generics were not part of .NET). Just **cast** it to `obj` type: `var obj = (PersonList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` Variable correctly contains an instance of that type but simply compiler can't know it at compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You updated your question with a request for a generic cast and Generics is exactly what you're looking for.

```
public T Deserialize<T>(T obj, string path)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I'd remove the `obj` argument. It's solely purpose is to provide the type. The user will have to specify the type manually then.

Answer (score 1):

Your obj variable is declared as object instance. Do cast in Deserialize:

```
var obj = (PersonList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I was doing it that way before but I will be passing in loads of different types of objects so wanted a generic Deserialize function. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Will all of the different object types contain the property `lp`?

Comment: then your code is correct (your Deserialize function). Do cast later, after call of Deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

Your obj have type of **object**, so you can use only general methods of **object** class. You should cast obj to the type you need. For example:

```
obj = (PersonList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as PersonLis;
```

You can also use **is** operator to check if your **obj** belongs to **PersonList** class

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method for the XmlSerializer to use generic deserialization:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlSerializer serializer, StreamReader streamReader)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it by:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize<PersonList>(reader);

reader.Close();
```